# Flexbox grid animation with Flexbox

Tags: css, animation, flexbox, transition

I have a grid with Flexbox.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    width: 49%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.item:hover {
    flex-grow: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="background: red">a</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: green">b</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: blue">c</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: purple">d</div>
</div>
```

I want to animate the items on hover: the one below cursor grows in width and height, and the others stretch accordingly. I managed to do that only if `flex-direction: column;` is applied, but then is not a grid anymore:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    width: 49%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.item:hover {
    flex-grow: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="background: red">a</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: green">b</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: blue">c</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: purple">d</div>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Flex grow/shrink don't work when you have an explicit height/width set. Your `flex-column` version works because you don't have a height set. Remove `.item{width:49%;}` and the horizontal version works too.

If you want it to wrap use `flex-wrap` and `flex-basis:50%` but that's going to do odd stuff if they grow/shrink.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.item:hover {
    flex-grow: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="background: red">a</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: green">b</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: blue">c</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: purple">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you; can you come up with an example?

Comment: @Nikita see my answer for an example

Comment: Thanks @BryceHowitson; but your example is not a grid, is the same as my second try

Comment: Do you need the flexbox to grow or could the content grow? It's hard to recommend something without knowing what you're trying to accomplish with this layout.

Answer (score 0):

Make your default width lower. If you keep it greater than 33.3%, only 2 itmes will share a row

Added height change

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    width: 35%;   /* can not go under 33% */
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.item:hover {
    flex-grow: 22;
    min-height: 50%;
}
.container:hover .item:not(:hover) {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="background: red">a</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: green">b</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: blue">c</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: purple">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! thats grat, but this way the height is not growing. Is that possible?

Comment: Will you always have 4 items ? If this is the case, see the edited answer.

Comment: Yes, always 4 items, in same space.

Comment: No, the elements don't fill vertical space…

Comment: @Nikita If height changes are completely removed, would you be ok with the result?

Comment: Hi @LionelWong, not sure about what you mean. The idea is to do something like [this](https://codepen.io/erik127/pen/OvodQR), but only with css.

Comment: Changed the snippet. Check now.